# Combining rows on the x-axis within geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I assume I am asking a pretty simple question, however I am not able to solve it myself. How can I create age groups on the x-axis in the image below. For example, 10-20, 20-30, 40-50 etc. within `ggplot`?

[image]

I know I could create a new dataframe, but I prefer to keep my worksheet simple and do it within `ggplot`. This is the code I am using:

```
 figure1 <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x = factor(Leeftijd),)) + geom_bar() + xlab("Age") + 
ylab("Loneliness (count)") + ggtitle("Overview of the distrubtion of lonely people")

figure1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should probably use `geom_histogram()` with your preferred number of bins given to the `bins = ` argument.

Comment: Tried it, fyi this is the code I used: `ggplot(newdata, aes(x = factor(Leeftijd))) + geom_histogram(bins = 20) + xlab("Age") +
  ylab("Loneliness (count)") + ggtitle("Overview of the distrubtion of lonely people")`. 

However, I got the following error message: `Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?` I am using a continuous variable, so I do not know how to deal with this error. Do you have any clues @mtoto?

Comment: Take out the `factor` call so `geom_histogram` (well, `stat_bin`, really) can tell what the order of the variable is, and therefore how to bin it. Also, to make your question reproducible you need to post enough data (preferably the results of `dput(newdata)`) to simulate the issue.

Comment: Great, removing `factor` did the trick :)!

Answer (score 0):

First a question you didn't ask but I want to answer. I've found it much better to feed my dataframe through dplyr and tidyr before it goes into ggplot.

It makes for much more readable code and makes the whole mess much simpler when you get your head around it.

Secondly, this does what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


## I created some dummy data here, you want to use your own, obviously
newdata <- data.frame(as.numeric(round(rnorm(1000,50,10))))
colnames(newdata) <- c("Leeftijd")


figure1 <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x = factor(Leeftijd),)) + geom_bar() + xlab("Age") + 
  ylab("Loneliness (count)") + ggtitle("Overview of the distrubtion of lonely people")

figure1


## This does what you want, change the binwidth to whatever you're interested in.
newdata %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x=Leeftijd) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=10, stat="bin") +
  labs(x="Age",
       y="Loneliness (count)",
       title="Overview of the distribution of lonely people")
```

Comment: Loading `dplyr` or `tidyr` makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I always load them - I need dplyr to pipe into ggplot